# Atoms and their bonds in an explosion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atoms, atomic-physics

I was watching a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8ZOf8xp1no) and when the car did blow up I asked to me... what happens with the atoms and their bonds when an object blows up of this way? what is the behavior of the atoms and their bonds when an object is on fire? what is the atomic structure of the fire?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Temperature is just a kinetic energy of an atoms, if this energy is enough to break this bonds, molecules will just break apart.

Comment: but if the fire is made of atoms obviously why the fire have that aspect? exist some special reason? or I need ask that to God?

Comment: When temperature (Kinetic energy) of atoms is high enough and it will react with oxygen (in other words it will start burning) then it will emit light, it's because of atoms are made of electrons, and these electrons emit light with certain frequency at certain temperature (kinetic energy of an atoms) (mostly in infra-red spectrum).

Comment: When electron which is in high energy state and moves to low energy state it emits light, and it's energy is calculated using this equation $E=hf$ where $h$ is Plank's constant and $f$ is frequency of light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a branch in physics which studies fire, it's called [combustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion).

In a nutshell, there's a state when matter is burning which is basically a plasma. In plasma, the matter ionizes, i.e. bonds are broken, electrons are all flying around etc. The system as a whole is still neutral, but it's composed of ions and other charged particles which normally are bound in molecules.

That's not the only thing that happens when materials burn. There are all kinds of intermediate states, when it's not quite plasma yet.

To those who can read Russian or love Google translate, here's [the syllabus](http://mipt.ru/aspirantura/kandidat/major/f_60umgl/a_6164j5.php) of the PhD comprehensive exam on chemical physics of combustion and explosion, it has the references to textbooks and other literature at the end.

Comment: can you provide to me some text to read more about that??

Comment: @Hector, this isn't my field. The only book I know of is [Zeldovich](http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Shock-High-Temperature-Hydrodynamic-Phenomena/dp/0486420027/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1399577821&sr=8-1&keywords=zeldovich). He's one of the guys behind Soviet nuclear bomb project, he must know a thing about combustion :) I'm sure there are more modern texts though